# Is there a way to edit the markup of comment_form()?

Tags: comment-form

I have a single.php page where I call the `the_content()` function, followed by the `comment_form()` function to display the comment box.

While this function does display the logged in user, link to log out, textarea for comment, and post button, and I can edit the CSS, I'm wondering if there a way to edit the markup that is generated.

I've found a [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/partial-and-miscellaneous-template-files/comment-template/) that details the markup of comment.php from TwentyTwenty theme, but does not include the markup for said comment box.

The two main things I'd like to do is; add the users avatar next to the comment box, and add css classes to the button and textarea for styling.

Answer (score 0):

I covered just the other day some of the comment (textarea) filters here, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/366147/144392

But the filters you may want to look into are most likely,

- [comment_form_fields](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_form_fields/)
- [comment_form_field_{$name}](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_form_field_name/)

**EDIT 11.5.2020:** Codex example for [`comment_form($args)`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comment_form/),

```
$comments_args = array(
        // Change the title of send button 
        'label_submit' => __( 'Send', 'textdomain' ),
        // Change the title of the reply section
        'title_reply' => __( 'Write a Reply or Comment', 'textdomain' ),
        // Remove "Text or HTML to be displayed after the set of comment fields".
        'comment_notes_after' => '',
        // Redefine your own textarea (the comment body).
        'comment_field' => '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">' . _x( 'Comment', 'noun' ) . '</label><br /><textarea id="comment" name="comment" aria-required="true"></textarea></p>',
);
comment_form( $comments_args );
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm creating my own theme so I don't have the`comment-template.php` file. I've created it, edited the markup and called it using ` <?php comment_form('/comments-template.php'); ?>` but the markup is still the default. Am I doing something wrong? p.s. the path is correct

Comment: @Chillin' I'm sorry, I read your question poorly. The `comment_form` function takes as the first parameter an array in which you can include the required modifications. You can see all of the available keys for the config array in the code reference, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comment_form/.